# Android notifyDataSetChanged doesn't work in Gridview

Tags: android, gridview, refresh

I don't know why the `notifyDataSetChanged` doesn't work in my gridview. I my retrofit event `onResponse` I call the method to refresh my gridview items and there is no changes...

**Retrofit call**

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<PictureInfos> call, Response<PictureInfos> response) {
     PictureInfos infoResponse = response.body();

     infoResponse.save();
     pictureInfos.add(infoResponse);
     adapter.updatePicturesList(pictureInfos);
}
```

**Gridview BaseAdapter**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private List<PictureInfos> mPInfoList;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<PictureInfos> pInfoList) {
        mContext = context;
        mPInfoList = pInfoList;
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        Log.v("5", "" + pInfoList.size());
    }

    public void updatePicturesList(List<PictureInfos> pInfoList) {
        mPInfoList = pInfoList;
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mPInfoList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view;
        final ImageView imageView;
        final TextView legend;

        // Soft display
        if(convertView == null){
            view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.thumbnail_gallery, parent, false);
        }else{
            view = convertView;
        }

        // Get layout item (Image and Legend)
        imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_thumbnail);
        legend = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_thumb);

        // Get the download path image
        String pic = Globals.SERVER_NAME+Globals
                            .ACCOUNT_SERVER_PATH+mPInfoList
                            .get(position).getFolderPath()+"/"+
                            VgzTools.addSuffix(mPInfoList.get(position).getFilename(), "-thumb");

            Glide.with(mContext)
                    .load(pic)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                    .into(imageView);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Do you have an idea to fix that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked server response ? Are you getting more objects ?

Comment: Of course I get the good response

Answer (score 1):

> try this:

```
@Override

public void onResponse(Call<PictureInfos> call, Response<PictureInfos> response) {
     PictureInfos infoResponse = response.body();
pictureInfos.clear();
pictureInfos.addAll(infoResponse);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: debug your code and find out what values you are getting in infoResponse  and one more thing, use addAll instead of add.

Comment: the on response is good. I have all my datas. But when I do a .clear() this will reset all List<PictureInfos> in this activity

Comment: post your variable/list declaration here.

Comment: there are all private member to my Activity class

Comment: If I do that http://pastebin.com/jVjb0n8f the `clear()` on the `pictureInfos` List  will set `pi` List  size to 0...

Comment: I hope your pictureInfos is not static.

Comment: No : private List<PictureInfos> pictureInfos;

Answer (score -1):

when you define `List<PictureInfos> mPInfoList` as final you will understand what is wrong.

Comment: can you be more specific?